# Retrieving and loading different text sources through intents

Tags: android, android-intent

Okay my title may not be the most descriptive, but basically what I want is this:
I have 2 buttons and 2 activities. the buttons are in `ActivityA` the `ActivityB` contains only one `TextView` that sets it's text based on the button that was pressed and the message it carries using the intent. For example
`buttonA` is set to change the text in  `AactivityB` to "I am a boy" while
`buttonB` is set to change the same `TextView` In the same `AactivityB` to "I am a girl".
how do I receive this intent in `ActivityB` and set the text without using 2 `TextViews`.
Please I'm texting from my phone so I can't really post code because the system would start bugging me with indenting.
I'll appreciate any ans. thanks

here it is, the buttons I'm using are menu buttons in the overflow:

```
@Override   
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.aboutGospel:
Intent intent = new Intent(WebViewActivity.this,    AboutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("gospel", "hi im gospel");
startActivity(intent);
return true;    
case R.id.aboutPeters:
Intent tent = new Intent(WebViewActivity.this, AboutActivity.class);
tent.putExtra("peters", "hi im peters");
startActivity(tent);
return true;    
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

what I'll need now is this: the 2nd activity has just one textview in it. I'll like to set the text in that text view based on which menu item was clicked. please I'll love it if you help me with that, because this is just a test app, I'm building something larger and this function will help save time instead of creating multiple layouts or text view. thanks a bunch in anticipation.

Comment: please I'm pretty new to this, I'd appreciate if you go a step further. please make an actual example for me, using a Textview on the second activity to receive the intent n set the text it carries.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the data on the intent and you can get the data from the intent.
The intent you are passing will carry the data on the same key say gender so you can get the data from the extra with the same key.

Example -
 You can get the data from extra in `ActivityB` as

```
String gender = getIntent().getStringExtra("gender");
```

You can send the data on the intent as from `ActivityA` as-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtra("gender","I am a male.")//Female for the another button.
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I did that already, by using the intent. putExtra function.
intent.putExtra("boy", "I'm a boy")
startActivity(intent)
now on the next page, please write how 
I'll retrieve this info n set the text.
PS note that the above code is used in a switch statement, and the key to the 2nd button is " girl". thanks

Comment: Use the same key for both, You will be able to get the data in another activity properly.

Comment: please I'm pretty new to this, I'd
appreciate if you go a step further. please
make an actual example for me, using a
Textview on the second activity to receive
the intent n set the text it carries. thanks

Comment: @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected
(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.aboutGospel:
Intent intent = new Intent
(WebViewActivity.this,
AboutActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("gospel", "hi im
gospel");
startActivity(intent);
return true;
case R.id.aboutPeters:
Intent tent = new Intent
(WebViewActivity.this,
AboutActivity.class);
tent.putExtra("peters", "hi im
peters");
startActivity(tent);
return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected
(item);

Comment: what I'll need now is this: the 2nd activity has just
one textview in it. I'll like to set the text in that
text view based on which menu item was clicked.
please I'll love it if you help me with that, because
this is just a test app, I'm building something
larger and this function will help save time instead
of creating multiple layouts or text view. thanks a
bunch in anticipation.